# NODEJS mongodb how to put variable inside like query

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I need to put variable inside mongodb **like** query. This is my code

```
  query={username: /req.params.data/}
  Users.find(query,function(err,users){
    if(err){
      console.log(err);

    }
    else{
      console.log(users);
    }
  });
```

req.params.data is a variable.I need to look for user that contains it.

Comment: Why are you passing a regular expression, then?

Comment: I'm newbie with nodejs. Im passing the data with ajax to the controller. And I need to find the user.

Comment: So what exactly is the *problem*? Do you see errors? Unexpected outputs? Note that you're not actually *using* the value of `req.params.data`; it's probably best not to throw in random syntax like slashes if you don't know what you're doing.

Comment: I know, I tried to put in random text and It worked ,than I tried to put it like this query={username: "/"+req.params.data+"/"} but it doesn't take it as a like query for some reason idk why.

Comment: You need to make an actual regex, not just a string that looks like one, but using the value. Try `new RegExp(req.params.data)`.

Comment: That worked thank you. :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`req.params.data` is a variable and will contain the passed username from front end.

```
 var userName = req.params.data; 

 User.findOne({ 'username': userName })
     .then(function(user){...})
     .catch(function(err){console.log(err)});
});
```

Ok if you need to perform a like search then use [**RegExp**](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/regex/).

```
User.find(username: new RegExp(req.params.data));
```

or the old way is

`User.find(username: {$regex: "/^" + req.params.data + "/"});`

Comment: Okay, I get this but I need to get it inside like query.

Comment: This doesn't solve the OP's problem; that's still not a like query. Also it's helpful to explain the changes you've made (or just stick with the callback they were already using).

Comment: @bzzzzzz updated answer